# Building plasma-desktop fails because the development release of KDE-Frameworks isn't installed

Tags: cmake, kde-plasma, kdevelop

### Summary

I'm trying to make changes to a KCM (application style to be exact) which is part of plasma-desktop, so obviously I need to build that.
However, on attempting to do that, it complains about needing extra-cmake-modules (ECM) 5.57 when I only have 5.56.
Fair enough, I downloaded the current cmake repo and installed it. Now the compiler complains that my KDE frameworks aren't "up-to date" as well.
If I understand correctly, 5.56 is the latest stable release and 5.57 is not at that point yet, which is why it's not in the Arch Linux repositories but development versions of KDE need depend on it. I don't want to install that.
This problem might be even worse on other distros, I remember trying to build some KDE app on Fedora, which failed because the KF5 version was even older.

### Actual Question

- How can I install the dependencies needed to build something without installing them to the system itself?
- Do I even need to build the entire plasma-desktop when I only care about one little KCM?

Comment: Google for `kdesrc-build` and `kde craft`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you are building the development version (`master` branch). In this case, you also need the complete KF5 building environment from `master` branch. This is only recommended for experienced developers.

If you have older versions of Qt5 and/or KF5 installed, you can only build older branches. Examples for the `plasma-desktop.git` repository:

- [Plasma/5.15](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/?h=Plasma%2F5.15) branch requires [KF 5.54.0 and Qt 5.11.0](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/tree/CMakeLists.txt?h=Plasma/5.15)
- [Plasma/5.12](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/?h=Plasma%2F5.12) branch (LTS) requires [KF 5.42.0 and Qt 5.9.0](https://cgit.kde.org/plasma-desktop.git/tree/CMakeLists.txt?h=Plasma/5.12)

To get the sources of a branch, use `git checkout Branchname` in the cloned git folder. Alternatively, you can download older source code versions as `*.tar.xz` files from https://download.kde.org/stable/plasma/

Now to your questions:

- If you really want to build the development version, and want to avoid also building unstable versions of the KF5 dependencies, several distributions already offer extra repositories or PPAs with unstable development versions of KF5. I suggest to ask in a forum of your distribution how to find those. For KDE neon, there exists the [KDE neon Developer Edition](https://neon.kde.org/download).
- There is no need to build the complete package. You need to configure (using `cmake OPTIONS`) the complete build system for the package, but then you can `cd kcms/style` into a subfolder, and run `make` and `make install` only there.